# Difference between すれ違う, 外れる and ずれる plus something about grammar

Tags: grammar, word-choice, kanji, song-lyrics

I've heard in a song the following line:

> すれ違い心見えたなら
> 「要らない，要らない」しないのに
> 貴方はいつも貴方のまま

This seems to mean something like "If I met someone whose feelings differed from mine, I wouldn't say 'I don't need it, I don't need it", but you are like you have always been". I have no confidence at all in this translation and I would appreciate it if someone came up with a better one. I also would like to know why it's 見えたなら and not 見えたのなら.

Anyways, it seems that すれ違い means something like "to differ" or "to go against". However, I looked up at some dictionaries and it seems that すれ違う means almost the same as 外れる and ずれる. Are there any differences? Moreover, what is the kanji for すれ違い's すれ?

Answer (score 1):

Is that a lyric from "Ame no Murakumo P(あめのむらくもP)" from "Taningoto no oto ga suru(他人事の音がする)"?

**すれ違い　心見えたなら 「要らない要らない」 しないのに

貴方はいつも貴方のまま 時に呑まれ　錆びるよ 崩れ落ちて　果てるよ**

---

> I have no confidence at all in this translation and I would appreciate it if someone came up with a better one.

I'm not a good translator of lyrics and poetry, so I'll skip it. I'm sorry.

---

> I also would like to know why it's　見えたなら and not 見えたのなら.

The word "のなら" indicates an assumption, and "なら" indicates a case (assertion).

When you say to someone who looks hot, 「暑い"なら"、クーラーをつけましょうか」 The "なら" is a suggestion to understand that the other party is hot.
But 「暑い"のなら"、クーラーをつけましょうか」,
You don't know if they're hot or not, but "if it's hot ..."
Thus, including "の" would be a suggestion involving assumptions.

---

> Moreover, what is the kanji for すれ違い's すれ?

In kanji, it is written as "擦れ違う".

> Anyways, it seems that すれ違い means something like "to differ" or "to go against". However, I looked up at some dictionaries and it seems that　すれ違う means almost the same as 外れる and ずれる. Are there any differences?

It refers to passing close enough to each other to touch each other.
It shows that those mindsets seem to be incomprehensible to each other.
So in the case of this lyric, it would mean "miss each other."